# How to write to Mongoid array or hashes in forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a recipe model and an ingredients model, in my recipe model I have and field of type array called ingredients. in this array I am trying to store the ID of a selected ingredient from the ingredients model and and the quantity of that ingredient. 
e.g.

```
['chicken',400,'rosemary',5, ...]
```

The view I am trying to create would then look something like this

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :ingredients %><br>
<%= f.collection_select %> #ingredients from db
<%= f.text_field %> #Ammount in grams
</div>
```

the idea is that when listing the ingredients all I have to do refrence

```
ingredients[1] || ingredients[2]
ingredients[3] || ingredients[4]
.
.
ingredients[n] || ingredients[n]
```

basically that the content of each field in the form will just add to the array in sequence.

The reason I want to store them like this is once I have list of ingredient ID's I then need to query the ingredients DB and calculate total nutritional values such as calories or protein but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend using an embedded document here for the ingredients. The array might be nice and compact but creating to form for an embedded document is much easier. You will also have more possibilities to querying the db by the ingredient's fields.

PS: For arrarys use `text_field_tag 'something[]'` to make the an array.